# Windows store app SSO using windows AD

Tags: authentication, active-directory, windows-store-apps

Is there way to enable SSO on windows store app using windows AD? (the current user logged in will be authenticated)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2014/08/21/forget-login-screens-how-to-add-single-sign-on-for-universal-windows-store-phone-apps.aspx

the class you are looking for is OnlineIdAuthenticator